# How to use startActivityfoResult in Android studio 2.3.3?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 activities. MainActivity and Screen2. I want to send a text written in the EditView from MainActivity on pressing the button to Screen2, display it on the EditView there. Then on pressing the button on Screen2, it needs
to return it to MainActivity and display a concatenated message. But my app keeps closing, please help me

```
package com.example.car.cerdo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String msg;
    public static final String Extra_Message = "myFirst";
    static final int Main_requestCode=1;
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Screen2.class);

                msg = t.getText().toString();
                myIntent.putExtra(Extra_Message, msg);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent,Main_requestCode);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==Main_requestCode)
        {
            String msg= data.getStringExtra(Screen2.Result_Message);
            t.setText(msg);
        }
    }
}
package com.example.car.cerdo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Screen2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    String msg;
    public static final String Result_Message="my_Res";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen2);

        Intent i=getIntent();
        msg=i.getStringExtra(MainActivity.Extra_Message);
        TextView t= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t2);

        t.setText(msg);
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent resultIntent= new Intent();
                resultIntent.putExtra(Result_Message,  msg+" this is new");
                setResult(RESULT_OK,resultIntent);// REsultcode
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

EDIT: WAS CORRECTED AFTER Mr.UMAR HUSSAIN'S ANSWER, YET THE PROBLEM REMAINS THE SAME. I'VE ADDED THE LOG UNDER THE COMMENTS SECTION OF THE QUESTION PLEASE CHECK THAT TOO

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Comment: 09-02 10:48:34.119 1598-1598/system_process W/IInputConnectionWrapper: reportFullscreenMode on inexistent InputConnection
                                                                       
                                                                       [ 09-02 10:48:34.123  1365: 1365 I/         ]
                                                                       free_cache(3063) avail 701313024
09-02 10:48:57.358 2622-3201/com.google.android.gms I/FA-SVC: This instance being marked as an uploader
09-02 10:49:12.861 2622-2632/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool:

Comment: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/networkstatistics.sqlite' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

Comment: That looks like an error occuring elsewhere..Check the given answer .. Maybe that is your problem?

Comment: Can you add a break point or `Log.d()` call at the beginning of `onActivityResult()` to see if it is called? If not, place other break points and or log calls in other strategic locations to see what is happening.

Comment: Do you get an error message when your app closes? Or does it just exit normally to the launcher?

Comment: The app does not even get started. it just says cannot open, the app keeps closing

Answer (score 1):

In first activity, in onActivityResult you are receiving string using "Result_Message" as stirng while you are sending from screen two using "my_res" string. instead of calling variable from Screen2 you just put the variable name in string for solution see the below code

Do this in your MainActivity.java:

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==Main_requestCode) {
        String msg= data.getStringExtra(Screen2.Result_Message); 
        t.setText(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `"Result_Message"`? This seems to be used both as a variable name and as a String literal.

Comment: I'm sorry, please explain where on onActivityResult have i received the string using My_Result? Thanks for taking time btw :)

Comment: This is certainly an issue. Not sure if it is the only problem here since it does not explain why the app quits completely. Also, you can improve your answer by explaining the difference between a variable name and a String literal.

Comment: @ShivaShankari Please refresh the page to see the edited answer.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice your are right, since setting null in textview doesn't thow an exception. There will be other issue.

Comment: Thanks a ton but still the app is not working. when i try to launch it, it says , the app keeps closing